# Can I correct an error on a visa application?

Tags: visas, uk

I am applying for an EEA national permanent visa and the planned date of arrival is not correct on the application form submitted. Am I able to cross it out and write in the new one? I am from Spain and submitted the application to the British Embassy.

Comment: Hi, you need to tell us to whom you have submitted your application, then we can reopen and give an answer. At the moment you could have submitted your application to East Teacup and we would be none the wiser.  Please edit, thanks

Comment: To the EEA national permanent visa

Comment: "the EEA national permanent visa" does not denote any _organization or group of people_ that you could have submitted an application to. You're being asked WHOM YOU SUBMITTED THE APPLICATION TO, not _what you're applying for_ (though the latter is also relevant, of course, but don't silently rewrite clarifying questions into another question that you feel more like answering).

Comment: Good! You have submitted an EEA application to a British Consulate General.  I have asked the community to reopen your question so that you can get lots of really great answers. Standby...

Comment: @pnuts vote dude, we'll give the benefit of the doubt :)

Comment: If you are from Spain you do not need a visa. There is also no such thing as an *EEA permanent visa.* It sounds like you may be applying for an *EEA family permit* for the non-EEA family member of an EEA national; is that correct?

Comment: Did those proposed duplicates have to do with "arrival date"?

Answer (score 3):

You have submitted your UK application to the VFS in Spain and you notice that there's an error in the planned arrival date field and want to correct it...

> Am I able to cross it out and write in the new one?

At the stage where you print the application, but before you report to the VFS, you can make a small pen and ink correction to the paper form.  Use a single line to cross out the wrong date and enter the correct date above it.  It must be indelible ink (no pencil, or eye liner, or whatever -- and yes, I have seen someone use eye liner on a UK application form).  Make an ink notation in the 'remarks' area to indicate what you have done.

This works if the correction is straight-forward, like a planned arrival date.  If the correction is more complex, then you need to delete the application and make a fresh one.  If they receive an application with lot of pen and ink corrections they will *reject* it (but not *refuse* it) and return it to you as an invalid application.

If you have already handed your application to the VFS, then there's little to be done except cancel it.  For reasons of security and "application integrity" they will never accept a change over email unless it's coming from a member of the [UK Law Society](https://www.lawsociety.org.uk/) who they know, and even then it needs to be a small, straight-forward error.

---

Note: Applications submitted to a VFS in Spain are sent to [Lunar House](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_House) for processing and decision-making. The turn-around is about 5 - 7 days.