# Proof of address for UK visa applications and correcting clerical errors

Tags: visas, uk, applications

I have made an error filling the UK visa form. In the address section I have typed in my address (I live in Australia) correct including post code but selected a different country.
I have my appointment to submit the printed copy of the application and supporting documents next week. What are my options to correct it?

- Can I cut off the incorrect country in the address and hand write the correct one and then sign there?
  Am I able to make changes on the printed copy?
- I'll be submitting my drivers licence copy as proof of address.
  So would this matter?

Comment: Not fully a duplicate because this one has an evidence question (driving permit) as proof of address.

Comment: Retracted my dupe-close vote. I had overlooked the proof-of-address part and also given there's an answer by @GayotFow it is better to leave the Q open as a reference. I have edited the title accordingly to highlight this part of the Q.

Comment: @mts nice edit, it puts the question into a broader and clearer light, thanks for that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You made a clerical error in your application.

Background first.  The current UK application is a page-by-page questionnaire where the answers to some questions induce the programme to ask more detailed  questions.  At the point when the user selects PayPal or one of the credit cards for payment, the programme raises a pop-up asking "Are you sure about everything in your application?"

If the user is sure and proceeds to make payment instructions, the application is frozen.  The user then prints out the application and proceeds to the biometrics centre.  BUT... When people discover a mistake after the application is printed, they flip out.

If the mistake is simple and involves something mechanical (like address or postcode), The user can make a neat pen-and-ink correction on the form itself.

If the mistake is complex, like clicking 'no' to a prior conviction, the user must abandon the application and start over from square one.  This includes forfeiting the fee.

End of background.  Your question...

> AM i able to make changes on printed copy?

Yes, given that the alteration is a simple and mechanical data item. Make a single line through the inaccurate item and hand write the correct information. Pedants will insist that you enter your initials in the margin. You can do that if you want, but I don't think it's necessary.

> Ill be submitting my drivers licence copy as proof of address. So
>   would this matter?

There is no explicit (or implicit) need to confirm your address. If you want to do that you should give an explanation of why you think it's important. Giving them irrelevant evidence will take longer to analyse and the assistants will wonder what they are supposed to do with it.

They would prefer a recent utility bill (or some similar type of invoice) in your name. Several of these would be 'golden'.  A driver's permit will do, but it is not 'golden quality'. Driving permits last for a long time and so the information may not be current. So if you really feel the need to confirm your address, the best option is to elevate the quality of your evidence.  In general, the address is not something people lie about and as mentioned above it is not a requirement.

---

- See also:
  [Clerical Error (or rounding differences) In a UK Visa Application](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62079/clerical-error-or-rounding-differences-in-a-uk-visa-application)
- also
  [Can I correct an error on a visa application?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/83220/can-i-correct-an-error-on-a-visa-application)
- also
  [Standard Visitor visa application in The Philippines submitted with error](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46209/standard-visitor-visa-application-in-the-philippines-submitted-with-error)
- and
  [Clerical error in UK visa application, but form already submitted - what should I do?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71639/clerical-error-in-uk-visa-application-but-form-already-submitted-what-should)