# Original supporting documents for UK Visitor visa-please clarify

Tags: visas, uk, applications

UK visitor visa checklist says provide original documents and a copy of each document.

Does term original applies to every document we need to provide? For example I know we can submit original birth certificate, marriage certificate, passport even bank certificates can get the certified version from bank but what about payslips, employer's letter of confirmation, tour itinerary and  all I can provide is printouts of the documents?

For example I work for a leading bank and our HR department is at a different location.They sent me the letter for visa purpose confirming the employment via email.I printed the PDF version of the letter. Payslips I printed from system. So is the letter from my real estate agent confirming  I live in my present address was a printout sent to me via email.
Is this OK? what do they mean by it has to be original?

It doesn't seem practical to get originals of every document. From what I know the process is VFS will scan the documents on the appointment date and return it then and there to the applicant, but will keep the passport? Therefore if it is anyway going to be scanned and sent by VFS does it matter that some documents are printouts of original because I have no way to getting the originals of them.

Comment: Obviously the answer is **NO**! Photocopies always accepted except when usually it comes to things like settlement visas etc when original birth certificates, marriage certificates, etc are requested for examination at some point. I know because I have submitted photocopies etc for many successful visa applications including UK visas. You have to use your **judgment**. For example in high fraud countries like Nigeria, they would place more emphasis on originals etc.

Comment: We talked about proof of address over here http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/91059/proof-of-address-for-uk-visa-applications-and-correcting-clerical-errors how can an estate agent help? Where does it say you need to confirm your address? Are you sure you are looking at the visitor guidance?

Comment: @Gayot Fow , document check list which generates after submitting the application asks for evidence of home address.examples given theee are mortgage deed/rental agreement.it asks for original document and a copy of each document you submit.not sure why is that when what vfs does is scanning the documents and returning to you

Comment: Make a screen cap or scan of what you are seeing. It is not in the mandatory documents page.